# Dangled with std::mt19937 and profiling the code with gprof

Tags: c++11, random, profiling, gprof, mersenne-twister

I have in my .h file this code:

```
std::mt19937 rng(time(NULL)); // mersenne numbers
int random(int n) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n);
  return distribution(rng);
}
```

but I **never** call `random()`.

When I am profiling the code with gprof, I get:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 99.13      2.28     2.28        1     2.28     2.28  random(int)
```

What is happening?

Comment: Does it still appear if you replace the function body with a `return 0;` or a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); return 0;`?

Comment: If your using -O3 the compiler aggressively inline everything, so it might mix up the code for rng and random if rng could use some of the code in random. Try again using -O0

Comment: @Surt that's it! stefan, since the other solution worked, I didn't test yours. Surt, you can answer the question, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using -O3 the compiler aggressively inline everything, so it might mix up the code for rng and random if rng could use some of the code in random. Try again using -O0